# FullText SQL Server Clustered Service Move

Tags: sql-server

I need to move the I drive from one san vendor to another.  Microsoft states that you can't move the fulltext http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q304282& and the only way would be remove the cluster and re-install the cluster.  Does anyuone know of any other way?  Would swapping the old I drive for a new I drive work?  Currently on the I drive I just have the fulltext directory and sql server log directory to move.  The later I know how to handle.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Windows 2003 - SQL Server 2005 32bit and yes this is one of the few 2005 instances that we have left

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping out the old drive for the new one will work; I have used this to migrate to new SAN volumes with little problem.

- Add drive letter (X) to new drive
- Add X drive to the cluster
- Shutdown the instance
- Copy drive contents from I drive to X drive
- Change drive letter of I to Z
- Change drive letter of X to I
- Change dependency of cluster resources to new I drive (in 2003 this can be a little tricky but I don't have any servers to give you examples)
- Take Z drive offline
- Bring instance back online
- Rinse and repeat until the service comes back online.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I've been debating going this way or with clusterrecovery.exe tool.  Do you prefer one way over the other?

Comment: I don't have any experience with clusterrecovery.exe, sorry.  As long as you copy all the files and folder and retain the drive letter the FT service shouldn't notice one way or the other about the new disk.  The cluster group is the only part where changing out the disk has given me trouble.